# C5.0: How do I extract error percentage from summary into a variable?

Tags: r

Preface: My question is *not* a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30085692/109941).

---

The following code:

```
library(C50)
data(iris)
fit <- C5.0(Species ~ ., data=iris)
summary(fit)
```

Produces the following output:

```
Call:
C5.0.formula(formula = Species ~ ., data = iris)


C5.0 [Release 2.07 GPL Edition]     Sun Sep 13 16:06:01 2015
-------------------------------

Class specified by attribute `outcome'

Read 150 cases (5 attributes) from undefined.data

Decision tree:

Petal.Length <= 1.9: setosa (50)
Petal.Length > 1.9:
:...Petal.Width > 1.7: virginica (46/1)
    Petal.Width <= 1.7:
    :...Petal.Length <= 4.9: versicolor (48/1)
        Petal.Length > 4.9: virginica (6/2)


Evaluation on training data (150 cases):

        Decision Tree   
      ----------------  
      Size      Errors  

         4    4( 2.7%)   <<


       (a)   (b)   (c)    <-classified as
      ----  ----  ----
        50                (a): class setosa
              47     3    (b): class versicolor
               1    49    (c): class virginica


    Attribute usage:

    100.00% Petal.Length
     66.67% Petal.Width


Time: 0.0 secs
```

My Question:

- How can I extract the error percentage (2.7%) into a variable?

My motivation:

- I have my own dataset, and I'd like to vary training set sample size in order to produce a learning curve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about `sum(predict(fit,iris) != iris$Species)/nrow(iris)`?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
> stringi::stri_extract(fit$output, regex = "\\(?[0-9.]+\\)?%")
[1] "2.7%"
```

Answer (score 1):

From looking at `summary(fit)$output` The output is a real mess. The only way I found to was `regexpr()` it out. This is messy and really doesn't get waht you want but you can cut out the string you want from the secondary mess.

```
library(C50)
data(iris)
fit <- C5.0(Species ~ ., data=iris)
substr(summary(fit)[1],regexpr("Errors",summary(fit)[1])[[1]]-1,regexpr("Errors",summary(fit)[1])[[1]]+30)
```

I would then substring out the percentage.

Not pretty, but it works.